# WARN {SourceHandler} - I/O error: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? wso2 Micro integrator 4.2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

```
 ~/downloads/internship/wso2mi-4.2.0/bin/ sh micro-integrator.sh
[2024-02-12 12:52:13,626]  INFO {PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through HTTP Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8290
[2024-02-12 12:52:13,627]  INFO {PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through HTTPS Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8253
[2024-02-12 12:52:13,628]  INFO {StartupFinalizer} - WSO2 Micro Integrator started in 2.82 seconds
[2024-02-12 12:52:13,686]  INFO {PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through EI_INTERNAL_HTTP_INBOUND_ENDPOINT Listener started on 0.0.0.0:9201
[2024-02-12 12:52:13,694]  INFO {PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through EI_INTERNAL_HTTPS_INBOUND_ENDPOINT Listener started on 0.0.0.0:9164
[2024-02-12 12:52:21,456]  WARN {SourceHandler} - I/O error: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
[2024-02-12 12:52:22,482]  WARN {SourceHandler} - I/O error: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection
```

I did not modify any file how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to access a service through the HTTPs port (8253) via HTTP protocol. If using the SSL port the protocol needs to be `https://`

```
https://localhost:8253/something

OR

http://localhost:8290/something
```

Comment: [2024-02-12 16:53:49,258]  WARN {SourceHandler} - I/O error: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
[2024-02-12 16:53:49,258]  WARN {SourceHandler} - I/O error: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
[2024-02-12 16:53:49,327]  INFO {LogMediator} - main sequence executed for call to non-existent = /carbon
@ycr

Comment: @SaifEddineLayouni How are you invoking the service?

Comment: I run this 
 ~/Downloads/internship/wso2mi-4.2.0/bin/ sh micro-integrator.sh
then I put this link in google chrome browser 
https://localhost:8253/carbon
and this the response :
This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: "https://localhost:8253/carbon"
HTTP ERROR 404

Comment: http://localhost:8290/ and https://localhost:8253/
the both does not work
http et https

Comment: There is no Admin portal (/carbon) in Micro Integrator. If you want to access the Management UI you need to deploy the Dashboard component of MI. (https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/observe/mi-observe/working-with-monitoring-dashboard/)

Comment: @SaifEddineLayouni If you want to just check if MI is running, try `http://localhost:9201/healthz`

Comment: {"version":"4.2.0", "update_level":"30", "status" : "ready"}
this was displayed on browser 
and this on the terminal :
WARN {InternalAPIDispatcher} - No Internal API found to dispatch the message to : /favicon.ico
WARN {PassThroughHttpSender} - Trying to submit a response to an already closed connection : http-incoming-1, CORRELATION_ID = 944a3770-a329-41a6-af2a-a55874c0931b
WARN {InternalAPIDispatcher} - No Internal API found to dispatch the message to : /healthy

Comment: @SaifEddineLayouni What are you trying to accomplish here? Just ignore those errors and warnings. They are expected as you are trying to do random things on the server without deploying anything on the server.

Comment: Initially, I'll start by learning WSO2 Micro Integration. Then, I plan to leverage this knowledge to construct an integration platform, incorporating WSO2 Identity Server and API Manager.

Comment: I want to understand how a project works with Micro Integrator and Micro Integrator Dashboard as it works fine, but when I use Integration Studio, the same project doesn't work.

Comment: i use this project
https://mi.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/get-started/quick-start-guide/